# Network graph layout issue using lay_out_with_fr() in Shiny app - some nodes not positioned correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have created a Shiny app that generates a network graph using ggplot and the lay_out_with_fr() function in R. The graph represents the distance of hotel ratings from a target hotel. While the layout generally works well, I'm encountering an issue where one or two nodes are not positioned as expected. Specifically, high-rating nodes are supposed to be closer to the target node, and low-rating nodes should be farther away. However, in some cases, this relationship is not being maintained.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(igraph)
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)
library(tibble)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shiny::tags$head(
    shiny::tags$meta(name = "viewport", content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5")
  ),
  span(textOutput("notFound"), style = "color: red; text-align: center;"),
  uiOutput("plot"),
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data2 <- tibble(
    HotelName = rep(c(
      "DoubleTree by Hilton Amsterdam Centraal Station",
      "Leonardo Hotel Amsterdam Rembrandtpark",
      "Corendon Amsterdam New-West, a Tribute Portfolio Hotel",
      "Novotel Amsterdam City",
      "Mercure Amsterdam City Hotel",
      "Van der Valk Hotel Oostzaan - Amsterdam",
      "Park Plaza Victoria Amsterdam"
    ), times = 3),
    Rating = rep(c(5, 7, 4, 1, 8.9, 3.5, 1.5), times = 3),
    Price = rep(c("BDT 25,080", "BDT 61,525", "BDT 41,200", "BDT 25,000", "BDT 18,000", "BDT 10,200", "BDT 1,200"), times = 3),
    Reviews = rep(c("2,901", "2,500", "1,500", "1,300", "1,800", "1,456", "5,456"), times = 3),
    RoomType = rep(c("Double", "Triple", "Family"), each = 7)
  )
  
  
  
  
  
  # set.seed(123)
  # Only single room type not implemented
  if (length(data2$RoomType) == 1 || length(data2$RoomType)==0) {
    output$notFound <- renderText("Can't execute the code with one hotel")
  }
  else {
    
    # any single value excluded
    data <- data2 %>% group_by(RoomType) %>% filter(n() > 1)
    
    # seperate lists based on RoomType
    hotelInfo <- split(data, data$RoomType)
    
    
    # browser()
    
    # initialize the target hotel
    targetHotel <- "DoubleTree by Hilton Amsterdam Centraal Station"
    
    # generate plot
    generatePlot <- function(targetHotel, hotelInfo) {
      # select index of target hotel
      rowIndexOfTargetHotel <- which(hotelInfo$HotelName == targetHotel)
      # extract number only
      updateRating <- str_remove_all(hotelInfo$Rating, "[^0-9.]")
      # separate target hotel
      edgeRatings <- updateRating[-rowIndexOfTargetHotel]
      
      # display first three words of hotel name 
      firstThreeWords <- sapply(str_split(hotelInfo$HotelName, "\\s+"), function(words) paste(words[1:3], collapse = " "))
      
      nodes <- tibble(id = 1:length(hotelInfo$HotelName), label = firstThreeWords)
      
      edges <- tibble(
        from = rep(rowIndexOfTargetHotel, length(hotelInfo$HotelName) - 1),
        to = setdiff(1:length(hotelInfo$HotelName), rowIndexOfTargetHotel),
        rating = edgeRatings
      )
      
      graph <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes, edges = edges)
      
      # E(graph)$edge_size <- (str_remove(edgeRatings , "^r-"))
      E(graph)$edge_size <- as.numeric(edgeRatings)
      # browser()
      minC <- rep(-10, vcount(graph)) # minimum co-ordinate of graph
      maxC <- rep(10, vcount(graph))  # maximum co-ordinate of graph
      minC[1] <- maxC[1] <- 0
      layout <- layout_with_fr(graph, 
                               weights = E(graph)$edge_size,
                               minx=minC, maxx=maxC,
                               miny=minC, maxy=maxC
                               # grid = 'grid',      # set 'grid' for stop plot randomness
                               # niter = 1000,       # Number of iterations
                               # area = 10^2,        # Optimal area of the layout
                               # repulserad = 0.1    # Radius of the repulsion force
      )
      # browser()
      
      TargetnodeSizefor2=24.5
      Neibornodesizefor2=22.5
      TargetnodeSizeforALL=32.5
      NeibornodesizeforALL=26.5
      
      hjustnode=0.5
      
      ggraph(graph, layout = layout) +
        geom_edge_link(aes(label = rating), label_colour = "gold",
                       angle_calc = "along", # angle_calc is set to "along," it means that the edges will be drawn along the calculated angle based on the layout of the graph.
                       alpha = 1/5,
                       show.legend = FALSE,
                       start_cap = circle(5, "mm"),
                       end_cap = circle(5, "mm"),
                       color = "lightgrey", width=1) +
        geom_node_point(aes(x = layout[, 1], y = layout[, 2], color = as.factor(nodes$id)), 
                        size = ifelse(nodes$id == rowIndexOfTargetHotel, ifelse(length(hotelInfo$HotelName) == 2, TargetnodeSizefor2,  TargetnodeSizeforALL), ifelse(length(hotelInfo$HotelName) == 2,  Neibornodesizefor2,  NeibornodesizeforALL ))) +
        geom_node_point(aes(x = layout[rowIndexOfTargetHotel, 1], y = layout[rowIndexOfTargetHotel, 2]), 
                        color = "lightblue3", size = ifelse(length(hotelInfo$HotelName) == 2, TargetnodeSizefor2,  TargetnodeSizeforALL), show.legend = FALSE) +
        
        geom_text(aes(x = layout[, 1], y = layout[, 2], label = str_wrap(nodes$label, width = 13)), 
                  color="black",
                  fontface=ifelse(nodes$id == rowIndexOfTargetHotel,"bold", "bold"),
                  vjust = 0.2, hjust = hjustnode, 
                  size = ifelse(nodes$id == rowIndexOfTargetHotel, ifelse(length(hotelInfo$HotelName) == 2, 3, 3.3), ifelse(length(hotelInfo$HotelName) == 2, 2.5, 2.8)),
                  check_overlap = TRUE) +
        geom_node_text(aes(label = hotelInfo$Price), vjust = 2.7, hjust = hjustnode, color = "black",fontface=ifelse(nodes$id == rowIndexOfTargetHotel,"bold", "bold"), size = ifelse(nodes$id == rowIndexOfTargetHotel, ifelse(length(hotelInfo$HotelName) == 2, 3, 3.3), ifelse(length(hotelInfo$HotelName) == 2, 2.5, 3.2))) +
        annotate("text", x = layout[rowIndexOfTargetHotel, 1], y = layout[rowIndexOfTargetHotel, 2],
                 label = hotelInfo$Rating[rowIndexOfTargetHotel],vjust = 4.6, hjust = hjustnode, size = ifelse(length(hotelInfo$HotelName) == 2, 2.8, 3.5), color = "darkblue", fontface="bold") +
        theme_void() +
        theme(
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
          plot.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
          plot.margin = margin(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, "cm"),
          legend.position = "none"
        )
    }
    
    
    output$plot <- renderUI({
      lapply(1:length(hotelInfo), function(rowIndex){  # lapply - iterative function works like loop(map function)
        fluidRow(
          style = "display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;",
          column(
            width = 12, align = "center",
            
            h3(paste0("price", names(hotelInfo)[rowIndex], "Room"), align = "center", style = "margin-bottom: 40px; margin-top: 50px"), # Added plot title
            
            plotOutput(paste0("plot-",rowIndex), width = "600px", height = "575px") 
          )
        )
      })
    })
    
    lapply(1:length(hotelInfo), function(rowIndex){
      output[[paste0("plot-",rowIndex)]] <- renderPlot(generatePlot(targetHotel, hotelInfo[[rowIndex]]))
    })
    
  }
}

shinyApp(ui, server)`
```

I aspect the distance of the nodes from the target node are based on rating.